# I'm trying to dynamically call to a folder based on path of my program

Tags: python, pyinstaller

My .py program is `/Desktop/TEST/program.py`.
The executable I want to run is `/Desktop/TEST/ExampleProgram/example.exe`
I want to be able to call `example.exe` and send CLI commands to it as though I am in `/Desktop/TEST`.

I can do this easily if I hard code the paths into the program like `/full/file/path` I need to know how to dynamically change this path depending on where the my program is ran from as in `/run/location/cli/arguments/`. I'll be using pyinstaller to turn the main .py into a .exe

I have tried doing this with `("%s" % path.abspath(path.curdir))` paired with the `subprocess` module. However, I feel like this is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do - maybe `os.chdir()` to CHangeDIR ? OR maybe you need to use relative path `ExampleProgram` ? OR use `..` to go to previous folder ? If you want full path to folder with script then better use `path.abspath(__file__)` or `path.abspath(sys.argv[0])` because it can be started from different folder and then `path.curdir` can be different folder.

Comment: BTW instead of `"%s" % path.abspath(path.curdir)` you can use directly `path.abspath(path.curdir)`

Comment: Okay, say I have myprogram.exe inside folder Program
Inside the 'Program' folder I also have another folder called FFMPEG
I have ffmpeg.exe in there and I want to be able to call the program regardless of where the main program is extracted.

Comment: it is still not clear - where are these folders. `somefolder/Program/myprogram.exe` and `somefolder/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe` ? But always it is good to get full path to `myprogram.exe` because if system starts `myprogram.exe` in `otherfolder` (as CurrentWorkingDirectory (`os.getcwd()`)) then relative paths `../FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe` will do `otherfolder/../FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe` instead of `somefolder/Program/../FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe`

Comment: Well for now these folders are in a fixed location. However, once I finish the app I assume users will use it in all different locations. Desktop, documents, programs, where ever they extract my Programs folder that has [My program, folder with ffmpeg] (and eventually more) 

So, I need assistance on how to set the paths of the .exe in the subfolder dynamically based off of the current working directory instead of hardcoding C\Folder\Folder .I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `program.exe` in

```
C:/Desktop/TEST/Program/program.exe
```

and you want to access

```
C:/Desktop/TEST/Program/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe
```

then theoreticaly you would need only relative path

```
FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe
```

and it should use it as full path

```
C:/Desktop/TEST/Program/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe
```

But often system may start `program.exe` in different folder (so called `"Current Working Directory"` which you can test with `os.getcwd()`)

If it runs your `program.exe` with current working directory

```
C:/OtherFolder
```

then using `FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe` it would search

```
C:/OtherFolder/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe
```

and it is better to find full path to `program.exe`

```
PROGRAM_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

and later always use

```
os.path.join(PROGRAM_DIR, "FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe")
```

---

**BTW:** If you use PyInstaller to create `exe` then you can see some information in [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html) - see [Using sys.executable and sys.argv[0]](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0)

Comment: I cannot upvote you, as I'm new to this whole scene, coding etc. I've only been doing it for about 2 weeks. 

However, that is exactly the explanation that I needed and it instantly solved my problem. Thank you sir! :)

Comment: Im not sure if you'll see this but when I use the method above it breaks my command line arguments being sent to the console

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. If you have new problem then create new question on new page and you will have more space for code and description. Eventaully  add it to current question